# SQL Server : SUM results in arithmetic overflow without actually exceeding INT limit

Tags: sql, sql-server, integer-arithmetic

I have following SQL query:

```
SELECT SomeId, COUNT(*) AS Entries, SUM(Field1) AS MySum
FROM MyTable
WHERE SomeId IN (......~400 items......)
GROUP BY SomeId
```

And it throws this error:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

`Field1` is `INT`. I know that `INT` max value is 2147483647. But the issue is that sum of all `Field1` is nowhere near `INT`'s max value. Maximum of `Field1` value is 156, maximum sum of single group is 600 and sum of all sums in the result set is just 14660.

If I cast `Field1` as `BIGINT`, it does work, but I don't think this is proper solution.

I've found out that this query works only if I reduce number of IDs in `WHERE IN` clause. And this has nothing to do with specific "problematic" IDs. If I leave only first half of IDs it works, if I leave second half it works too, but they don't work together for some reason. Any suggestions?

UPDATE

I've found another workaround which also can be implemented with EF Core. Join can be used instead of `WHERE IN`:

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM SomeIdTable WHERE Id IN (...)) AS x ON x.Id = SomeId
```

Interesting thing is that execution plan says this costs 49% when compared to initial `WHERE IN` query.

This is just a workaround and it doesn't solve issue of random "arithmetic overflow" caused by `WHERE IN` with too many values.

Comment: If `SUM(Field1)` doesn't work and `SUM(CONVERT(bigint,Field1))` does, then something in your `SUM` is bigger than `2147483647`.  you claim it isn't, but the fact that one works and the others doesn't proves this otherwise. Also, I'd suggest using a table variable to hold your values, rather than using an `IN`, if you have 400 odd values.

Comment: Then why `SUM(CONVERT(bigint,Field1))` doesn't return anything bigger than 600? Why `BETWEEN` with first and last IDs works without casting?

Comment: Internally an `IN` expression is translated as a (potentially huge) forest of `OR` branches (`WHERE SomeID = ... OR SomeID = ... OR ...`) This does, at times, trip up the optimizer in complex cases, although I can't say whether it's the case here. Try two things: 1) `SELECT * INTO NewTable FROM MyTable WHERE ID IN ...` and then do the query on that, to confirm your base data is not the issue, and 2) insert the IDs in a temp table or table variable and write the `IN` using a `SELECT` subquery, to reduce the complexity of the query tree.

Answer (score 0):

If your ~400 items are sequential you could try using the `between` command, ie:

```
SELECT SomeId, COUNT(*) AS Entries, SUM(Field1) AS MySum
FROM MyTable
WHERE SomeId BETWEEN 'FIRST_VALUE' AND 'SECOND_VALUE'
GROUP BY SomeId
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately `BETWEEN` won't work here. These are specific IDs. The interesting thing is that the query DOES work with `BETWEEN` clause and returns 4k groups instantly without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert to bigint only in the query, not the table def.

```
SELECT SomeId, COUNT(*) AS Entries, SUM(convert(bigint, Field1)) AS MySum
FROM MyTable
WHERE SomeId IN (......~400 items......)
GROUP BY SomeId
```